# Content of Django flatpages not stored

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg, django-flatpages

I have added the flatpages package and tried to add a flatpage in the admin interface. The title and URL are added, but not the content of the page. The content of a flatpage is edited in the YAHOO.widget.Editor. Does anyone know why the content of a flatpage isn't stored and know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work without the YAHOO.widget.Editor? Maybe you could also show the code you used to get the YAHOO.widget.Editor to appear.

Comment: While this isn't exactly to the point, if you're just looking for WYSIWYG editing in flatpages and the YUI editor continues to be problematic, django_tinymce is a nice super easy solution with built-in support for just this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django developer James Bennet added TinyMCE to flatpages in his book Practical Django Projects. His code is available on BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/practical-django-projects/src/79e75633cbd4/cms/

I've used his example in a project using flatpages before, and it worked great. Give it a try.